# Увидеть сеть хоста из гостевой ОС

Tags: linux

Всем привет, установлен virtualBox на нем стоит гостевая ОС - Ubuntu, основная ОС - windows 10. Вопрос таков, как увидеть из Ubuntu хостовую ОС по сети? В Ubuntu подключены два адаптера NAT и виртуальный адаптер хоста, каждую ос пингуется из другой, но сеть в Ubuntu не появляется.

Comment: Вам нужен тип сети bride. В этом случае гостевая система будет иметь полноценный внешний айпи и будет работать как почти полноценная машина.

Comment: Я поставил тип сети bridge, но всё равно не удается увидеть хост. Я хочу, чтобы он был виден по пути network->WindowsNetwork

Comment: а, так и нужно писать. Для этого нужно установить и настроить samba

Comment: можете подсказать как это правильно сделать?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/samba   нужен именно сервер, иначе другие не будут видеть. Также нужно очень аккуратно настроить группу, но это все виндовые заморочки